# Mutation Chaining in apollo superGraph

Tags: graphql, apollo, mutation, mutation-chaining

I need to insert record in through one SubGraph and based on returned Id I want to update record in another SubGraph. Looks like apollo doesn't support mutation chaining directly (can't pass Id from one mutation to the other one).

Can we do a query, get an Id and then use that in a mutation ?
Something like:

`get an id from Subgraph 1`

`make mutation call to subgraph 2 with Id returned in first query`